# touchstart vs click in mobile device

Tags: javascript, android, ios

I'm developing some JS application and I need to detect when user clicks by some image; so, I see that for mobile devices there is 'touchstart' event besides 'click'. But I prefer to use 'click' event, because Safari doesn't open new tab in 'touchstart' event. So, my question: if I use only 'click' event will it work in any mobile device or not?

Comment: The `click` event is fully supported on all mobile devices. I don't see why not.

Comment: It depends on what framework you are developing. For instance, if you are developing in Ionic2 which is on top of AJS, then the framework gives you options for click, drag, double click and so on.. But from your questions its not clear whether you are developing app running in browser or as a mobile application

Comment: my app just runs in mobile browser